# unity3d - Fire bullet using AddForce is very slow

Tags: unity, bullet-physics

This is a top-down view but in 3D coordinates, I would like to instantiate and fire a bullet from the player's gun. This script is on a spawner object at the end of the barrel.

```
void Fire () {

        float speed = 80;

        GameObject projectile = Instantiate (bullet, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;

        projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * speed);
        coolDown += Time.time;
    }
```

I also tried this but in this case the bullet always moves in a fixed direction (North) :

```
projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.forward * speed;
```

`Bullet` is an empty object and the actual bullet is it's child ( did that to overcome a rotation issue ), the problem is nomatter how high I turn up the speed the bullet travels very very slow. 
Both the parent and the bullet have `Rigidbody`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Force = Mass * Acceleration`, so in order to accelerate an object to 80 you'd have to apply a force of `80 * Mass` for one second.

If you want to instantly accelerate the object to a set speed, you should pass [`ForceMode.VelocityChange`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html) into `AddForce`. That will instantly change the object's velocity to what you want.

```
projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * speed, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```